# Us 3ds to buy a AU game

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I have a US 3DS and I want to buy Mario and Luigi paper jam from AU will the game work on my 3ds? And also what are the differences in the us version and AU version if I got it?

Comment: How do you know if it's region locked?

Comment: It is locked to the region of the device. It will not work with games from other regions.